# Multi-index calculation to new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this.

```
status               new                    allocation          
asset                csh       fi        eq        csh   fi   eq
person act_type                                                 
p1     inv           0.0      0.0  100000.0        0.0  0.0  1.0
       rsp           0.0  30000.0   20000.0        0.0  0.6  0.4
       tfsa      10000.0  40000.0       0.0        0.2  0.8  0.0
```

The right three columns are percent of total for each act_type. The following does calculate the columns correctly:

```
# set the percent allocations
df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["allocation",'csh']] = df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",'csh']] / df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",:]].sum(axis=1)
df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["allocation",'fi']] = df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",'fi']] / df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",:]].sum(axis=1)
df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["allocation",'eq']] = df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",'eq']] / df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",:]].sum(axis=1)
```

I have tried to do these calculations on one line combining 'csh', 'fi', 'eq' as follows:

```
df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new", ('csh', 'fi', 'eq')]] / df.loc[idx[:,:],idx["new",:]].sum(axis=1)
```

But this results in ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names

Any suggestions how I can reduce these three lines to one line of code so that i'm dividing ('csh','fi','eq') by the account total and getting percents in the next columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `idx[:,:]` should be simplify by `:`, then use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) by `axis=0` and for new columns use `rename` with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1=df.loc[:, idx["new",('csh', 'fi', 'eq')]].div(df.loc[:, idx["new",:]].sum(axis=1),axis=0)
df = df.join(df1.rename(columns={'new':'allocation'}, level=0))
print (df)
status               new                    allocation          
asset                csh       fi        eq        csh   fi   eq
person act_type                                                 
p1     inv           0.0      0.0  100000.0        0.0  0.0  1.0
       rsp           0.0  30000.0   20000.0        0.0  0.6  0.4
       tfsa      10000.0  40000.0       0.0        0.2  0.8  0.0
```

Comment: You're the best. Thanks!